# How to align logo and menu items in one line?

Tags: html, css

I cant see my alignment in one line. logo, menu and right menu... Please help to achieve the final output. [image: Results]

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* background-color: #CDCDCD; */
}

.top-menu {
  margin-top: 40px;
  /* background-color: #95E659; */
}

header {
  /* width: 100%; */
}

.logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.menu {
  float: left;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
  margin-right: 55px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #303030;
  font: 14px lato;
}

.menu ul li:first-child {}

.menu ul li:nth-child(6) {
  margin-right: 300px;
}

.search-container {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <header>

    <div class="top-menu clearfix">

      <div class="menu">

        <div class="logo">
          <a href=""><img src="assets/images/logo.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Women</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Men</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Kids</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Coming Soon</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>

          <li>
            <a href=""><img src="assets/images/user.png" alt=""> Login</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href=""><img src="assets/images/bucket.png" alt=""> Basket</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="search-container">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>





</div>
</header>


<hr>

</div>
```

Comment: why not using the flex box?! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: @HassanAliSalem ?I really dont know how to use them. I know the way of code I pasted here.

Comment: @HassanAliSalem why i cant achieve without flex box code?

Comment: tried `vertical-align: top;` + `display: inline-block;` already? however flexbox would be the right tool. Why use the for nearly 10 years outdated `float hack` when you simply could do it with flexbox which was exactly invented for that kind of issue.

Comment: There are vanishingly few reasons to use float in new code. Flex and grid will make your life much, much easier.

Comment: @rayhatfield is there any way to achieve without flex box?

Comment: @wardahamk of course you can achieve it without flexbox. But flexbox is a very easy solution to use than float and other solutions. It is more flexible and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start with flexbox.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.top-menu {
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #303030;
  font: 14px lato;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="top-menu clearfix">
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt=""></a>
        </div>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Women</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Men</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Kids</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Coming Soon</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/10" alt=""> Login</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/10" alt=""> Basket</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="search-container">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search">s</i></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use flex box for inline block elements. This will also give you a lot more control over the children elements and their layout.

I altered your HTML a little, adding the center menu buttons in a parent div and separating unordered list into two unordered lists. This way we can use flex to justify their content with `space-between` placing them on separate ends of the parent elements block.

On the menu `display: flex`, we also add a `flex` value for each child element, the logo, the menu buttons parent div ***between*** and the login button. By placing these elements into their own parent divs, we can control the width using flex. To center the elements vertically, if our default axis for display flex is set to row, we can use the `align-items` property. This will align the items in that parent elements border vertically. `align-items: center`

The *logo* and *login buttons* parents both having a flex value of 0, which means they will take up only the space they need to show their content. The middle element, ***.between*** having a flex of 1 will mean it will take up the rest of the parent menus width. This will allow us to place a flex display on the UL elements and we can then set them on separate sides of the remaining sections width using `justify-content` on the UL elements parent element ***.between***.

Snippit best if viewed in full page view as you define the width of your wrapper to 1200px.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
}

.top-menu {
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: #95E659;
}

.logo {
  flex: 0;
}

.logo img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.search-container {
  flex: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.between {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;
}

.menu div ul.left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.menu div ul.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu ul li {
  flex: auto;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #303030;
  font: 14px lato;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="top-menu clearfix">

      <div class="menu">

        <div class="logo">
          <a href="">
            <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="between">
          <ul class="left">
            <li><a href="">Women</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Men</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Kids</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Coming Soon</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="right">
            <li>
              <a href=""><img src="assets/images/user.png" alt="">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href=""><img src="assets/images/bucket.png" alt="">Basket</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="search-container">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search">search</i></button>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I feel your code a bit more lines in code.... I prefer less code ... but i appreciate your answer. thank you very much...