# How can I align menu items next to a logo image?

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists, nav

I just can't put the navigation bar correctly.

Here is a picture of it and where I want the text to be:

[image]

and here is the HTML and the CSS of it-

```
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="img.png" width="9%"></a>
        <div class="mean-toggle"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>




header {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1450px;
    max-height: 125px;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color:#069370;
}

nav {
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

nav ul {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: auto;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(50, 100, 200);
    font-family: 'Secular One', sans-serif;
}

nav ul li a.active, nav ul li a:hover {
    background: rgb(200, 50, 100);
    color: rgb(150, 200, 50);
    transition: 1s;
}
```

all I need is to get the content in the middle of the navigation bar
but it is impossible, so if you know some way than please write to me,
thanks.

Comment: This comes up on a daily basis. Don't use floats. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68074642/how-to-align-logo-and-menu-items-in-one-line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align logo and menu items in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68074642/how-to-align-logo-and-menu-items-in-one-line)

Answer (score 0):

Look up flexbox if you want to do this the best way, but if you really must use floats then remove

```
nav {float:right;}
```

and replace it with

```
nav {overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display:flex`

or use float left for img